# Not seeing aliases after sourcing .bash_aliases in script called from crontab

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alias, cron

I have the following in /tmp/get_env:

```
joeuser@doghouse:> cat /tmp/get_env

source /home/joeuser/.bash_aliases
env > /tmp/joeuser.env
alias > /tmp/joeuser.alias
echo $PATH > /tmp/joeuser.path
```

I have the following in my user crontab:

```
joeuser@doghouse:> crontab -l

* * * * * /tmp/get_env
```

I can see the crontab fires correctly and the script executes:

```
joeuser@doghouse:> ls /tmp/joeuser.*

-rw-rw-r-- 1 joeuser joeuser    0 Jun 23 12:23 joeuser.alias
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joeuser joeuser  106 Jun 23 12:23 joeuser.env
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joeuser joeuser   14 Jun 23 12:23 joeuser.path
```

but nothing defined in .bash_aliases is showing up in any of the files.

I've also tried sourcing the .bash_aliases in crontab directly, same result.

```
* * * * * source ~/.bash_aliases; /tmp/get_env
```

After an hour reviewing dozens of other things that can go awry with cronjobs, I still haven't figured out why I can't see definitions like this from .bash_aliases?

```
joeuser@doghouse:> cat /home/joeuser/.bash_aliases

alias rmi='rm -i'
export ANSWER=42
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it. cron runs in sh, not bash, where as I discovered when I changed the first line of /tmp/get_env to 'source /home/gitwatch/.bash_aliases 2> /tmp/source_error' the 'source' command isn't defined (and all the syntax is different anyway).

Adding a sh'bang '#!/bin/bash' as the first line of /tmp/get_env resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `man alias`:

> Note aliases are not expanded by default in non-interactive shell, and
>   it can be enabled by setting the `expand_aliases` shell option using
>   `shopt`.

The first command of `/tmp/get_env` should be:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: Once I added the sh'bang to /tmp/get_env it has no issue with expanding aliases in the script. They won't be expanded in crontab definitions itself; not sure how they would be handled if I had sh'banged to /bin/sh. In any case, thanks for the input!

Comment: Great! Congrats for solving the issue by yourself.